# Script to remove duplicates from database

Tags: php, sql

I have database in which I have data like phonenumber, orgno, companyname, postalcode.

Some duplicates are also in my database like same companyname, same orgno, same postalcode but different same phone no. So I want to remove these kind of duplicates by using a script. How can I write that kind of script?

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    address_id        bigint,
    name              varchar(255),
    marketing_name    varchar(255),
    co_address        varchar(255),
    box_address1      varchar(255),
    box_address2      varchar(255),
    box_postal_code   varchar(45),
    visit_address1    varchar(255),
    org_nr            varchar(255),
    visit_postal_code varchar(255),
    county_id         varchar(255),
    contact           varchar(255),
    complete          tinyint,
    deleted           tinyint,
    district_id       varchar(255),
    region            varchar(255),
    phone1            varchar(255),
    mobile_phone      varchar(255),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide what is the duplicate criteria that you will use. For example I want to check if the phone number is duplicate in the same Org Nro, company Name and postalcode. I can do this:

**First table for test**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
id int,
phonenumber int,
orgno int,
companyname varchar(100),
postalcode varchar(4)
)
```

**Then Test data**

```
  insert into TEST
 values (1,4533660,1,'COMPANY 1',1234)
  insert into TEST
 values (2,4533660,1,'COMPANY 1',1234)
  insert into TEST
 values (3,954189547,1,'COMPANY 2',4444)
   insert into TEST
 values (4,954189547,1,'COMPANY 2',4444)
   insert into TEST
 values (5,3652591,1,'COMPANY 3',4444)
   insert into TEST
 values (6,4201580,1,'COMPANY 4',4444)
   insert into TEST
 values (7,3337788,1,'COMPANY 5',4444)
```

**Finally, the query for duplicates, with the criteria selected.**

```
 Select phonenumber,
 orgno,
 companyname,
 postalcode,
 COUNT(*)
 from test 
 group by phonenumber,
 orgno, 
 companyname,
 postalcode 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

With this query, you can easy find duplicates, most important is review the criteria of duplicate.

***Edit***

If you want delete all duplicate rows except 1, you can do this:

```
DELETE A
FROM TEST A 
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY a.phonenumber,
        a.orgno,
        a.companyname,
        a.postalcode ORDER BY a.id)AS POS,
        a.phonenumber,
        a.orgno,
        a.companyname,
        a.postalcode,
        a.id
        FROM TEST A
        JOIN 
        (
                SELECT  
                phonenumber,
                orgno,
                companyname,
                postalcode,
                COUNT(*) AS CONTADOR
                FROM test 
                GROUP BY phonenumber,
                orgno, 
                companyname,
                postalcode
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) TB
        ON A.companyname = TB.companyname 
        AND A.orgno = TB.orgno 
        AND A.phonenumber = TB.phonenumber 
        AND A.postalcode = TB.postalcode
) TB_2
ON
a.id = tb_2.id 
and tb_2.pos > 1
```

> Edit, script using the data structure provided.

```
DELETE FROM TEST B
JOIN 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY
    a.org_nr,
    a.phone1,
    a.phone2,
    a.name,
    a.marketing_name
    ORDER BY 
    a.org_nr,
    a.phone1,
    a.phone2,
    a.name,
    a.marketing_name
    )AS POS,
    a.address_id,
    a.org_nr,
    a.phone1,
    a.phone2,
    a.name,
    a.marketing_name
    FROM TEST A
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        org_nr,
        phone1,
        phone2,
        name,
        marketing_name
        FROM TEST 
        GROUP BY 
        org_nr,
        phone1,
        phone2,
        name,
        marketing_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) TB
        ON a.org_nr = tb.org_nr
        and a.phone1 = tb.phone1
        and a.phone2 = tb.phone2
        and a.name = tb.name
        and a.marketing_name = tb.marketing_name
    ) TB_2
ON
b.address_id = tb_2.address_id
and tb_2.pos > 1
```

Comment: all rows having same postal code,same org and same phone number are duplicate.This is my criteria.I mean everything match the other one.

Comment: Adresses_id postal code orgno phone no company name
2234 85324 345268_9873 12345678 marketing
2235 85324 345268_9873 12345678 Marketingh
I have this kind of data more than 700000 adress i have in data base some of them are duplicates i mean the company name is same but some bad word added.

Comment: can you please provide a full example so i can help you much better?.

Comment: i have more than 30000 adresses record of players,having more than 12 column,col like(adressid,Name,orgno,phone,postaladresses,visitingadresses and z,y,z)some rows exactly same values so i want to find them and delete them from data base.i just join this forum so i am not so good how its work.can i attach the file?i mean to show you which type of data i have.

Comment: You can edit your post Including the table structure . Then if i understand you want to find values ​​With All columns Exactly right ? . Provide me table structure . Whatever you can adapt my script for your propose , putting all your columns in group by clausule, then check if the query retrieved the data correctly, and finally use delete from clausule like i will put in my post , i will edit it to teach you how to use the delete.

Comment: done, I add and script to remove all duplicates rows except 1, I think that you can improve the query.

Comment: Thank you so much but it doesnt work.i create a test and try to run this but it give me error

Comment: i deleted your post i thin,i am not able to view that now.The table you created i create that one and insert values into that.now want to delete the duplicates row for learning.then i will apply that script on my data.could you delete the duplicate row from that table,which you created earlier,so it would be easy for me to understand the process.

Comment: Why you try to edit  (or deleted) my post? lol. If you put your real Tabla estructure, I can help you much better.

Comment: How can i post my table here?i dont have any idea about that

Comment: Edit you own post, and then add the table estructura, like I put the table, CREATE TABLE TEST (col1 int, etc ... )...

Comment: juan ruiz unable to do that :-(

Comment: i edit in my question like these type of column i have and want to delet all rows which have duplicates.duplicate criteria fix for org_nr,phone1,phone2,name,marketing name.i hope now you will get it...

Comment: I suggest an edition, and there is a wrong in the table, in this column: address_id  bigint UN AI, what is UN AI?... and why tinyint data type have length of 3 ? tinyint cant have a length.

Comment: UN(unsigned)and AI is for auto increment.edition for what?

Comment: what DBMS are you using, is not SQL Server, what it is?... .

Comment: RDMS..I use the same query...just need a script which can find the duplicates and delete.

Comment: I am just trying to make PHP question which can find the duplicate from  my datatable and than remove them.

Comment: What happened?@juan Ruiz de castilla??

Comment: DBMS and RDBMS are equivalent, no RDMS, whatever i add a new script using your table estructure.

Comment: ok i will try this one.and what is TB in the script?And this will copy from test A and put in B after deleting the duplicate right?

Comment: TB and TB2 are alias from selects that make a new dataset. Dont forget that address_id need to be unique column preferably primary key, if is compoused, just add all the columns.