# Deleting a single duplicate row in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The image below is an example of what my table looks like. I have duplicate rows, but a unique feature `date_scanned`. What I am trying to do is remove a single row by specifying the `id`, but when I do that all the rows with that id are removed and postgres does not let you use LIMIT after DELETE.

The below works when I remove `WHERE id = 'F284'`, but will remove any row with rn =1. **I need to specify the row id**

```
DELETE FROM allergen_list WHERE date_scanned IN(
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date_scanned, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY id, lot, expiration_date ORDER BY date_scanned DESC) as rn
FROM allergen_list WHERE id = 'F284'
)
SELECT date_scanned FROM cte WHERE rn = 1;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf18E.png

Any help?

Comment: Please include sample data both before and after the desired delete operation.

Comment: Hi, look this old post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907712/3957327

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete all rows where date is less than max?

```
DELETE FROM allergen_list 
WHERE 
  id = 'F284' AND date_scanned < (
    SELECT MAX(date_scanned)
    FROM allergen_list WHERE id = 'F284'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Caius has the right approach.  However, the logic would appear to be:

```
DELETE FROM allergen_list al
WHERE al.id = 'F284' AND
      al.date_scanned < (SELECT MAX(al2.date_scanned)
                         FROM allergen_list al2
                         WHERE al2.id = al.id and al2.lot = al.lot and al2.expiration_date = al.expiration_date
                        );
```

Comment: That works thank you. I found that DELETE FROM allergen_list WHERE date_scanned IN (
                                        SELECT date_scanned
                                        FROM allergen_list
                                        WHERE id = 'someidnumber'
                                        LIMIT 1) works as well. When I tried something similar before, I didnt have the date_scanned column as a unique identifier.

Comment: @christophmckinzie . . . The solution in your comment looks highly dangerous, unless you want to delete random numbers of rows for all ids.  And that doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Well I only need to delete a single row, but it doesn't matter which one I delete as long as the lot number is specified (i accidentally put down id instead of lot).

Comment: @christophmckinzie . . . That version is not guaranteed to delete one row.

Comment: I don't understand enough to know why (obviously), but I'll take your word for it. Thank you Gordon.